# SVN: Delete deleted files

Tags: svn, visualsvn

I have checked out my SVN repo using `svn checkout {url}`. I moved some files from there (e.g. foo.cpp and foo.hpp) from folder `src` to `src2` (**Take a note that I deleted the original `src` folder**). When I use the following commands:
`svn add --force .`
`svn commit -m "%desc%"`
then I notice something strange. The console says that everything is done and revision number {whatever} is finished, but in the repo's UI (I'm using [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/)) it shows that **both folders** `src` and `src2` are retained. Either I'm using the wrong command or the wrong args. Or I'm just being a complete noob and forgetting the rules of SVN . Please help.

Comment: To rename, copy, move, or delete a folder one still must use `svn`, instead of doing it outside `svn`. Use [svn move](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) to rename or move a file or folder.

Comment: Technically that is a solution, but I'd rather have SVN detect that I deleted a file and automatically delete it for me, just like Git does.

Comment: To my knowledge svn does not do that. You have to be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dialecticus noted, you need to perform file operations in your working copy using SVN client (e.g., svn.exe, TortoiseSVN, etc.). Subversion does not automatically track move, rename, delete, copy operations — you need to run the corresponding commands manually. If you are using svn.exe client from command prompt, see [SVNBook | Basic Work Cycle](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/cycle/) and the [svn.exe command-line reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/).

If you are coding in IDE, then I guess that it either has built-in support for Subversion or an external integration plug-in that translates file operations made via IDE's UI to terms of Subversion. For example, there is the VisualSVN plug-in for Visual Studio. If you drag & drop or rename a file in Visual Studio, the plug-in automatically intercepts this operation and you don't need to track it manually and run SVN commands.